# How to add multiple layer on an image in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I whould like to have an image (of a map) in the application and to programmatically add
some layers on top of it (placeholders, paths, etc...)
I think that a photoshop-like layer approach could be helpful, but I have no idea of where to start.
Any simple example/link to tutorial or to documentation is useful :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm giving you a simple approach that you can build on:

- Create a empty Bitmap `finalBitmap`. This will be the final destination for all layers composition.
- Create a `Canvas` to draw to the `finalBitmap`. This canvas will be used to draw all layers into final bitmap.
- Create a `Bitmap` with your map image. Draw it to `finalBitmap` using canvas. This would be layer 1.
- Place markers, routes, etc. using the same approach. Those would be layers 2, 3, etc.

Exemple code:

```
//The empty Bitmap
finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(finalBitmap );
imageView.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap );


//Create the map image bitmap
Config config = Config.RGB_565;
Options options = new Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = config;
InputStream in = null;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {
        in = new FileInputStream(fMapImage);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        if (bitmap == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset :" + fMapImage.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset :" + fMapImage.getAbsolutePath());
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
}


//Draw the map image bitmap
Rect dst = new Rect(pt00.x, pt00.y, ptMM.x, ptMM.y);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dst, null);

//Here draw whatever else you want (markers, routes, etc.)
```

Regards

Comment: ok, this could work, but if I want to hide a layer can I do it with this approach? thanks

Comment: Yes. The layers need to be redrawn every time you make a change to them. If you want to hide one of them, you just don't draw it to the finalBitmap.

Comment: ok, I'd rather have something like `layers[1].hide()`, but I could try to figure out a way for doing this....what about a LayerDrawable?

Comment: I've never used it myselfe, but it's a class that draws from an array of `Drawables` and it's fine when all your items are drawables. But you also want to draw routes and markes, and you want to control the position where you want to place them. For example to draw a route you would used `canvas.drawLine()`, which you can't with `LayerDrawable`.

Comment: As I said, this is a very simple approach. I've used it to a similar objective and  I even implemented the mercator projection over the image to be able to place the markers and route correctly and it worked quite well for the objective I had.